# Fetching URL from HTMLData with List Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, regex, list

I'm near that I want, but I'm blocked...
I have `HTML` Data in my String contentString :
`Log.i(TAG, "ALL URL : " + contentString);`:

```
<p><b>14th April</b></p>
<p>The wind is south west with 4 to 5 foot of swell at the peak. Streedagh will probably be the best beach break.</p>
<p><span id="more-113"></span></p>
<p>High tide: 1250  3.1m    <span style="color: #ff0000;"> <a href="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/webcam/"><strong>CLICK HERE FOR LIVE PEAK WEBCAM</strong></a></span></p>
<p>Low Tide: 1854 1.4m</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<style type='text/css'>
#gallery-1 {
margin: auto;
}
#gallery-1 .gallery-item {
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
text-align: center;
width: 50%;
}
#gallery-1 img {
border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
}
#gallery-1 .gallery-caption {
margin-left: 0;
}
/* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */
</style>
<div id='gallery-1' class='gallery galleryid-113 gallery-columns-2 gallery-size-thumbnail'><dl class='gallery-item'>
<dt class='gallery-icon portrait'>
<a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery-113]" href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/11149460_10152656389992000_7842452340110509403_n.jpg'><img width="67" height="68" src="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/11149460_10152656389992000_7842452340110509403_n-67x68.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail colorbox-113 " alt="11149460_10152656389992000_7842452340110509403_n" /></a>
</dt></dl><dl class='gallery-item'>
<dt class='gallery-icon portrait'>
<a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery-113]" href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/14th-April.jpg'><img width="67" height="68" src="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/14th-April-67x68.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail colorbox-113 " alt="14th April" /></a>
</dt></dl><br style="clear: both" />
</div>
<p></p>
<p><b>3 day forecast to April 13th</b></p>
<p>Solid swell and onshore winds for the weekend. Best spots will be Rossnowlagh and Streedagh. Bundoran beaches and reefs will be blown out.</p>
<h1> Wind Charts</h1>
<p><a href="http://www.windguru.cz/int/index.php?sc=103244"><img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-747 alignleft" title="wind guru" src="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/wind-guru-67x68.jpg" alt="" width="67" height="68" /></a> <a href="http://www.xcweather.co.uk/"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-749" title="xcweathersmall" src="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/xcweathersmall2-67x68.jpg" alt="" width="67" height="68" /></a>       <a href="http://www.buoyweather.com/wxnav6.jsp?region=UK&program=nww3BW1&grb=nww3&latitude=55.0&longitude=-8.75&zone=0&units=e"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-750" title="buoy weather" src="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/buoy-weather-67x68.jpg" alt="" width="67" height="68" /></a> <a href="http://www.windguru.cz/int/index.php?sc=103244">Wind Guru</a>       <a href="http://www.xcweather.co.uk/">XC Weather</a>       <a href="http://www.buoyweather.com/wxnav6.jsp?region=UK&program=nww3BW1&grb=nww3&latitude=55.0&longitude=-8.75&zone=0&units=e">Buoy Weather</a></p>
```

I would like to fetch only href's URL with `<a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery-113]" ...>` (two in my example)

For that, I'm using Pattern :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a rel=\"prettyPhoto\\[gallery-113\\]\"[^>]*>");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(contentString);
        List<String> urlWithRel = new ArrayList<String>();
        String lastString;
        List<String> imagesUrl = null;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            urlWithRel.add(matcher.group());
            lastString = urlWithRel.toString();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "url with rel : " + urlWithRel);
        Log.i(TAG, "final url : " + imagesUrl);
        Log.i(TAG, "List size : " + imagesUrl.size());
```

With the first regex I can have the two markup I need :

`<a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery-113]" href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/11149460_10152656389992000_7842452340110509403_n.jpg'>, <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery-113]" href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/14th-April.jpg'>`

Now I want to store only href's URL, I find a regex that works for getting only url : **(?<=href=).*(?=>)**

But the problem is I can't use another regex on List... and if I create a string for making the regex, the regex is working just on the first object...

Here is my final code (doesn't work) :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a rel=\"prettyPhoto\\[gallery-113\\]\"[^>]*>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(contentString);
List<String> urlWithRel = new ArrayList<String>();
String lastString;
List<String> imagesUrl = null;
while (matcher.find()) {
    urlWithRel.add(matcher.group());
    lastString = urlWithRel.toString();
    Pattern lastPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=href=).*(?=>)");
    Matcher lastMatcher = lastPattern.matcher(lastString);
    imagesUrl = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (lastMatcher.find()) {
        imagesUrl.add(lastMatcher.group());
    }
}
Log.i(TAG, "url with rel : " + urlWithRel);
Log.i(TAG, "final url : " + imagesUrl);
Log.i(TAG, "List size : " + imagesUrl.size());
```

Returns :

```
final url : ['http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/11149460_10152656389992000_7842452340110509403_n.jpg'>, <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery-113]" href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/14th-April.jpg']
```

Comment: You're recreating the result list (imagesUrl) in the outer while loop, I don't think that's what you want. You search for your second pattern in matcher.group(), no?

Comment: Since contentString data it's actually html ,why not parse it with `jsoup` library and then get all the anchors in the document retrieving the ones that you need ?

Comment: @JPMoresmau Yes, I want to make another pattern on the first List (urlWithRel)

Comment: @MarcoDufal Can we stock the result in List after ? for example, add the first link in list[0] and the second in list[1] with jsoup ?

Comment: Yeah it's possible.. when you will get all the anchor they will be in an `Elements` object that's actually a list of `Element` objects and for each of them you will be able to call `attr()` method to get href (it will be a `String` so you can check if it `contains()` 'prettyPhoto..')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are willing to use the `jsoup` library this is the snippet you should use:

```
ArrayList<Url> urls=new ArrayList<Url>();
Document doc=Jsoup.parse(contentString);
Elements els=doc.select("a[href]");
for(Element el : els)
    if(el.attr("rel").equals("prettyPhoto[gallery-113]"))
       urls.add(new Url(el.attr("href")));
```

And remember to handle `MalformedURLException` for the `Url` object.